# Read Columns of different types in a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a .csv file using Numpy.
The .csv file has this format:

> ```
> U118,V078,3
> U106,V091,2
> U042,V057,5
> ```

I used numpy.genfromtxt function defining the data types in the argument:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('DATASET.csv', delimiter=",",names=['usuario','videojuego','puntuacion'],
                     dtype='str,str,int')
```

But what I am actually getting is only the int (3rd column) column:

```
> [('', '', 3) ('', '', 2) ('', '', 5) ('', '', 0) ('', '', 3) ('', '',
> 5)
```

Does someone know what I am missing?

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` expects a **list** of `dtypes`  to be assigned to attributes. So use `dtype = ['str', 'int', 'int']`

Comment: If you look at the `dtype` you'll see it's `U0', string type with space for 0 characters.  Some places it's ok to use `str` as the dtype, but for others, such as this, you need to specify the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the correct numpy nomeclature inside dtype? See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

If you're using a string to pass all dtypes, then perhaps something like

```
dtype = "S4,S4,i8"
```

Comment: Or in Py3, I'd use 'U4, U4, I8', the default string type.